# Wildfly 15.0.1.Final - Web Application Error

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, netbeans-8, wildfly-10, netbeans-8.2

### Wildfly 15.0.1

When I run a simple javaee 6 web application in wildfly 15.0.1 which was build under java 1.8 with netbeans 8.2 give the following error.

But when I browse the url application works fine.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080undefined"
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
        at org.netbeans.modules.ant.browsetask.NbBrowse.execute(NbBrowse.java:92)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080undefined"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:216)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:622)
        ... 31 more
```

### Wildfly 10.0.0

When I run a simple javaee 6 web application in wildfly 10.0.0 which was build under java 1.8 with netbeans 8.2 woks fine.

Is any one can describe why it happen and how to fix this issue it will be great helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update port number in the configuration file? `java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080undefined"` there is some special character or invalid char in your URL formation.

Comment: I didn't update the port number.But I set a offset.But i couldn't see any error on it.