# java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080undefined" when run or debug Netbeans Java Project in Wildfly 15

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, wildfly, wildfly-15

I have a JavaEE simple HelloWorld project developed using Netbeans. If I debug it or run it it works as expected in these situations (at least):

```
1) Netbeans 8.2 + Wildfly 12
2) Netbeans 10 + Wildfly 12
3) Netbeans 11 + Wildfly 12
```

but it fails (at least):

```
1) Netbeans 8.2 + Wildfly 15
2) Netbeans 10 + Wildfly 15
3) Netbeans 11 + Wildfly 15
```

The error shown when I try to run or debug using Wildfly 15 is:

```
Browsing: http://localhost:8080undefined/

java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080undefined"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at org.netbeans.modules.ant.browsetask.NbBrowse.execute(NbBrowse.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080undefined"
```

If I go deeper in the problem, it seems to be caused by wrong interpretation of ${client.url} on build-impl.xml, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

A workaround could be to add

```
<target if="do.display.browser.debug" name="debug-display-browser">
        <nbbrowse context="" url="http://localhost:8080/" urlPath="${client.urlPart}"/>
</target>
```

at the end of build.xml on the project root, but I would like to know how to fix the origin of the problem.

I have to say that the error is not blocking, that means that the project is successfully deployed, but the browser is not opened, what is somehow annoying. If I manually open the browser and write down the URL then everythings goes right.

Kind regards

Comment: `8080undefined` is not a valid port number See sections 3.1 and 3.3 in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: Thanks BankBuilder. That's obvious. The question is why netbeans is getting 8080undefined instead of 8080 (actual port). This information is, as far as I understand, retrieved from the xml configuration file of Wildfly. I can't see anything there different from version 13 to version 15 of Wildfly.

Comment: I don't think the port is the source of undefined, but rather the path. How are you setting the path in code?

Comment: It seems that it is not getting your webapp context

Comment: Well, I used the new project wizard, so both context and relative URL are default params: the wizard creates a jboss-web.xml with <context-root>/</context-root> and both context and relative URL can be seen on project properties. Relative URL is blank at the moment, but I tested several combinations and the error is the same regardless what I configure on context-root or relative URL.

Comment: @JMart There is a new NetBeans plugin for Wildfly which works. I updated my original answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***!!!! Updated on 10/5/19. There is now a solution - see the lower section of this answer. !!!!***

---

This is an answer, but unfortunately not a solution!...

- This is a possible duplicate of [Wildfly 15.0.1.Final - Web Application Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55057029/2985643), though no solution is offered.
- I can also reproduce your problem with Netbeans 8.2 + Wildfly 15, although it works fine with Wildfly 12. You are unlikely to get any fix for this from Oracle for NB 8.2.
- Note that there is an open bug report regarding the use of Wildfly with NB11: [NETBEANS-2415 Bring back support for WildFly server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2415). Apparently (at a minimum) there are licensing issues with the plugin:

  *AFAIK, there are license issues with that plugin. We have a contributor from them who tries to push the management to provide the wildfly plugin stuff with an Apache compatible license. If that does not work out the plugin might need to move to an external portal.*
- Also see open bug report [NETBEANS-2367 wildfly support disabled](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2367), and this this discussion: [No wildlfy plugin on Netbeans 11](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279950?_sscc=t)
- As you point out:

  - This is not a problem with Wildfly, but with NetBeans.
  - It is annoying, but not serious.

In summary:

- You will almost certainly not get a fix for your problem with NetBeans 8.2 from Oracle.
- For more recent releases of Apache NetBeans (>= NetBeans 9.0) it seems that Wildfly is not supported at present. Until that is resolved you won't get any fix for more recent NetBeans releases either.

---

***Updated on 10/5/19 to provide a true solution:***

- There is a [new Wildfly plugin available for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/76472/wildfly-application-server).
- See the recent discussion on [Bug Report NETBEANS-2415 Bring back support for WildFly server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2415) for more details.
- Download that plugin, then install it using **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins...**. NetBeans will restart.
- [Download and unzip the latest version of Wildfly](https://wildfly.org/downloads/) (if necessary), then on the **Services** tab select **Servers > Add Server...** to add that Wildfly Server.
- Create a web application and deploy and run it on that Wildfly server. It should work without any problems.

Notes:

- I verified this by creating a Maven web application on NetBeans 11.1, using JDK 13, and running it on Wildfly 18.
- As an unrelated matter, Wildfly 17 and later support Java EE 8.

Comment: Thanks @skomisa for deep research. I'm afraid my problem does not have a solution, at least by now, so I'm marking your answer as accepted since it helps understand the issue.